# Page.IsPostBack always returns false in sharepoint cutomized page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i added a customized with master page seattle, and deployed in folder in share point my problem is that Page.IsPostBack always return false.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: When are reading the property? Button click or some other event?

Comment: in page_load event

Comment: in page_load event

Comment: When are you checking this? When first time page is loading or after page load you click on some button?

Comment: in the second load after submit a button